# Choosing layer types for a neural network predicting the outcome of individual video game matches

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am working with this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/gabisato/league-of-legends-ranked-games/data

I am using the 'win' column as my target, having converted the data into 2 categorical one-hot vectors; one represents team 1 winning, and the other represents team 2 winning. These are stored in my trainY (600,1,1) and testY (56,1,1) numpy arrays.

I want to use the other 88 columns as predictors for the outcome of a match. As a result my trainX is (600,88) and my testX is (56,88). (One thing I have just thought of but am unsure of its merit: could/should I be creating a vector of length 1 for each of these features i.e. should my array be (600,1,1,1,1.....1)???)

In the class on neural networks that I am in now we have primarily used linear, convolutional, pooling, and dropout layers off the top of my head. I am working with keras and tried making a model using some random layers as a starting point:

```
#Define model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu',input_shape=(88,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=15, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model compiles fine, but I am running into the issue of my input lacking a dimension.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_30 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 88]
```

I have also been reading online that convolution is primarily useful for image processing and temporal data, which has me questioning my use of them at all in the first place. My issue is that we have only ever gone over examples relating to image recognition/labeling in my class, so I am really left at a loss as to how to approach my idea. Can I apply convolutional layers to my data? If so, how do I implement this extra dimension that Keras says I need? If I shouldn't be using convolutional layers, what would be an approach you could recommend in terms of my layering or even data preprocessing? All recommendations are gladly welcome, and I am not looking for code so much as conceptually what is the best way to approach building a neural network on data like this.

Here is my model fit code:

```
hist = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 10, batch_size=16,validation_data=(testX,testY))
```

Since it may be useful I will also add the code I used to split up the data:

```
#Dataframe to numpy array
challenger = challenger_df.to_numpy()
#Convert original labels of 1 and 2 to 0 and 1
challenger[:,0]=challenger[:,0]-1
#Define labels
LabelMeaning=['0=Team 1', '1=Team 2']
#preprocess features for network
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
for i in range(88):
  challenger[:,i+1]=scaler.fit_transform((challenger[:,i+1]).reshape(-1,1)).reshape(1,-1)
#Separate into train and test
train = challenger[:600]
test = challenger[600:]
print(np.shape(train))
print(np.shape(test))
print()
#Separate into X and Y
trainX = train[:,1:]
trainY = train[:,0]
testX = test[:,1:]
testY = test[:,0]
#check shapes for discrepancies
print(np.shape(trainX))
print(np.shape(trainY))
print()
print(np.shape(testX))
print(np.shape(testY))
print()
#Convert labels to one-hot vectors
trainY=np_utils.to_categorical(trainY)
testY=np_utils.to_categorical(testY)
print(np.shape(trainY))
print(np.shape(testY))
```

Comment: can you show your `model.fit` code?

Comment: Hi learner, I've added the code. Please let me know if you have further questions

Comment: the input to the neural network `trainX` is of the shape `[batch_size, 88]`. CNNs expect a 3 dimensional input and as they are generally used for images they expect input to be formatted as `(batch, steps, channels)`. If in your case you don't have the third dimension, you can use `trainX[:, :, None]` in `model.fit`. The documentation can be found [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/).

Comment: Thanks learner, I've gotten past that first error and the first epoch starts using this change, but I am receiving a new error now:


ValueError: Creating variables on a non-first call to a function decorated with tf.function.

Comment: Never mind with that last comment, I fixed the problem myself. It runs fine now, thanks a bunch!

Comment: glad I could help, I am going to put it down as an answer. Please accept it.

Comment: To accept an answer, you need to click the grey tick beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to the neural network `trainX` is of the shape `[batch_size, 88]`. Convolution Neural Networks expect input to be three-dimensional. From the documentation [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), the dimensions it expects are `[batch, steps, channels]`. However the provided input has only 2 dimensions, hence the error.

To make the input three dimensional you can add an extra dimension to the input data like so `trainX[:, :, None]`. This adds a `1` in the third dimension. However, the meaning of `channels` being `1` is something that you need to figure.